# Disable showing a minimized ribbon tab on click?

Tags: wpf, popup, ribbon, minimize

I use the Ribbon for WPF (2010 - `Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon`).

When `Ribbon.IsMinimized` is set to `true` the ribbon is minimized.

The normal behavior is that when I click on a minimized tab, it will open temporarily. *But is there any way to disable that, to prevent it from expanding?*

Comment: _When I Clicking on a tab, it's open a popup to display the items_.
What do you mean? When the ribbon is minimized, you see only the tabs.
To use the ribbon while it is minimized, you click the tab you want to use to expand it temporarily. Are you trying to change this behavior?

Comment: @PaoloMoretti Yes, I want to change this behavior: "To use the ribbon while it is minimized, you click the tab you want to use to expand it temporarily." It should not expand.

Comment: If you click the tab, nothing will happen? And you have to maximize the ribbon to have access ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please see the code below. Am not entirely clear on what you want, but I have covered 2 possible behavioural cases which hopefully meets your needs.

- Case 1:
  If the Ribbon is set to minimized and you click on a Ribbon tab, it will turn off the minimized flag, and turn the Ribbon into a non-minimized one from that point on. You can double-click the tab, or select the minimize Ribbon from the context menu to minimize again.
- Case 2:
  If you click on a Ribbon tab when the Ribbon is minimized it will keep the Ribbon in the minimized state.

I have provided 2 implementations of the code, one that just hooks a regular Ribbon, and another that creates a derived Ribbon.

```
<Window x:Class="DemoOfRibbonWithDifferentMinimizeBehaviour.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        x:Name="Main"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" xmlns:my="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/ribbon">
    <Grid>
        <my:Ribbon Height="254" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="ribbon1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="503" ItemsSource="{Binding}" IsMinimized="True" IsCollapsed="False" IsDropDownOpen="False" Loaded="ribbon1_Loaded">
            <my:RibbonTab Header="Fruits" KeyTip="F">
                <my:RibbonGroup Header="Berries">
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Grapes"/>
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Bananas"/>
                </my:RibbonGroup>
                <my:RibbonGroup Header="Pome">
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Apple"/>
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Pears"/>
                </my:RibbonGroup>
            </my:RibbonTab>
            <my:RibbonTab Header="Vegetables" KeyTip="V">
                <my:RibbonGroup Header="Root">
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Carrot"/>
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Turnips"/>
                </my:RibbonGroup>
                <my:RibbonGroup Header="Stalk">
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Bamboo"/>
                    <my:RibbonButton Label="Celery"/>
                </my:RibbonGroup>
            </my:RibbonTab>
            <my:RibbonCheckBox Label="Prevent Maximize" IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=Main, Path=PreventMaximize}">Prevent Maximize</my:RibbonCheckBox>
        </my:Ribbon>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Code behind of Window:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Navigation;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using Microsoft.Windows.Controls.Ribbon;
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
using System.ComponentModel;

namespace DemoOfRibbonWithDifferentMinimizeBehaviour
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Popup template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP;

        public bool PreventMaximize { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
            PreventMaximize = true;

            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ribbon1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP = VisualHelper.FindChild<Popup>(ribbon1, "PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP");

            if (template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP != null)
            {
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Height = 0;
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.StaysOpen = false;
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Opened += new EventHandler(template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP_Opened);
            }
        }

        void template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (ribbon1.IsMinimized)
            {
                ribbon1.IsMinimized = false;
                ribbon1.IsDropDownOpen = false;

                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            // Uncomment this if your intention is to prevent the Ribbon being maximized
            // i.e. keep it fixed in minimized mode.
            if (PreventMaximize)
            {
                ribbon1.IsMinimized = true;
            }
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // If you want to encapsulate the new behaviour in a new Ribbon class, then you
    // could use this instead of the above and modify your XAML appropriately.

    public class RibbonWhichPreventsMaximize : Ribbon
    {
        Popup template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP;
        EventHandler popupeventhandler;

        public RibbonWhichPreventsMaximize()
        {
            popupeventhandler = new EventHandler(template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP_Opened);
        }

        public override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            // Unwire the handler if this Ribbon control is getting a new Template applied
            // (e.g. for case when Template is dynamically changed at runtime).

            if (template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP != null)
            {
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Opened -= popupeventhandler;
            }

            base.OnApplyTemplate();

            template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP = VisualHelper.FindChild<Popup>(this, "PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP");

            if (template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP != null)
            {
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Height = 0;
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.StaysOpen = false;
                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Opened += popupeventhandler;
            }
        }

        void template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.IsMinimized)
            {
                this.IsMinimized = false;
                this.IsDropDownOpen = false;

                template_PART_ITEMSPRESENTERPOPUP.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
            }

            // Uncomment this if your intention is to prevent the Ribbon being maximized
            // i.e. keep it fixed in minimized mode.
            this.IsMinimized = true;
        }
    }

    //--------------------------------------------------------------------------

    // Note this routine taken from:
    // http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034522/how-to-find-element-in-visual-tree-wp7

    public static class VisualHelper
    {
        public static T FindChild<T>(DependencyObject parent, string childName)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            // Confirm parent and childName are valid. 
            if (parent == null)
            {
                return null;
            }

            T foundChild = null;

            int childrenCount = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(parent);
            for (int i = 0; i < childrenCount; i++)
            {
                DependencyObject child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(parent, i);
                // If the child is not of the request child type child
                var childType = child as T;
                if (childType == null)
                {
                    // recursively drill down the tree
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);

                    // If the child is found, break so we do not overwrite the found child. 
                    if (foundChild != null)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                else if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(childName))
                {
                    var frameworkElement = child as FrameworkElement;
                    // If the child's name is set for search
                    if (frameworkElement != null && frameworkElement.Name == childName)
                    {
                        // if the child's name is of the request name
                        foundChild = (T)child;
                        break;
                    }

                    // Need this in case the element we want is nested
                    // in another element of the same type
                    foundChild = FindChild<T>(child, childName);
                }
                else
                {
                    // child element found.
                    foundChild = (T)child;
                    break;
                }
            }

            return foundChild;
        }
    }
}
```