# VisualStateManager.GoToState doesn't work with DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, blend, visualstatemanager, visualstates

I have a Listbox with the following `DataTemplate` set as `ItemTemplate` and I want to change the `VisualState` of it using Codebehind.

DataTemplate:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="SortedRecommendationTemplate">
    <Border x:Name="asds">
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
                <VisualState x:Name="OnlyNameState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        ...
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
                <VisualState x:Name="OnlyImageState"/>
                <VisualState x:Name="AllInfoState">
                    <Storyboard>
                        ...
                    </Storyboard>
                </VisualState>
            </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <Grid>
            ...
        </Grid
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
```

This is the code I am using to get the Border (FindChild is from [How to find element in visual tree? wp7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7034522/how-to-find-element-in-visual-tree-wp7)) and change the VisualState

```
var blub = FindChild<Border>(listBox, "asds");
VisualStateManager.GoToState(blub, "AllInfoState", true);
```

However, GoToStates returns false. And blub really is the Border I want (well it is the first Listboxitem)
But the VisualStates seem to work because when I use the Behaviors from Blend they actually do change:

The triggers:

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseEnter">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="AllInfoState" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=asds}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
    <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeave">
        <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="OnlyNameState" TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=asds}"/>
    </i:EventTrigger>
```

Does someone know what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

This is because `Border` is not a `Control`, but a `FrameworkElement`. `VisualStateManager.GoToState(Control control, string stateName, bool useTransitions)` however only works with a `Control`.

You can use `ExtendedVisualStateManager.GoToElementState(FrameworkElement root, string stateName, bool useTransitions)` which you can find in Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity.Core. I guess this is what Blend uses internally.